# AppleScript Pages - get insertion point

Tags: applescript

I am trying to do some AppleScript-fu on iWorks Pages and want to insert a text box at the insertion point of a WP document. According to the dictionary for Pages there is an object called insertion point and it has an element called insertion point. However I can't seem to get anything:

```
tell application "Pages"
tell front document

-->set properties for text box
            set needs2Col to false
            set colHeight to 0
            if ((count of every item of headerFiles) > 5) then
                set needs2Col to true
                set boxH to (round ((count of every item of headerFiles) / 2) rounding up) * (font size of bookMarkStyle)
                set boxW to 6.5 * 72
                set boxX to 72.0
                            -->all these crash and burn with can't get errors
                            return insertion point of insertion point
                            return bounds of last paragraph of body text
                            -->all these return missing value
                            return insertion point of last paragraph of body text
                return insertion point of body text
            end if
end tell
end tell
```

Can anyone help me out here. I'm just looking for the x/y of the insertion point.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this question? (get insertion point)

Comment: I honestly don't remember, that was five years ago.

Comment: Ok, thanks, It seems it is impossible at least in new editions of Pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `character offset of (get selection)` to get the start of the selection or the location of the insertion point.

```
tell application "Pages" to tell document 1
    --start of selection
    character offset of (get selection)

    --end of selection
    tell (get selection) to character offset + length

    --move the insertion point after the second paragraph
    select insertion point after paragraph 2

    --move the insertion point to the start of the second page
    select insertion point before (paragraph 1 where page number of containing page is 2)

    --replace the selected text
    set selection to "aa"

    --selection as plain text
    contents of selection
end tell
```